# How to paste as plain text in android EditText by default

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

When I paste in Edittext in Android Studio, it paste color, underline and links also.
I only want it to paste it as plain text. I can do it by "paste as plain text" or through clipboard. But How can I do it by default by clicking on paste itself.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFV6X.jpg)

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textHome"
        android:layout_above="@id/submit_button"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="#F1F1F1"
        android:hint="Enter text here..."
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"/>
```

I tried changing inputType but still getting the same.